# PHP Error String

Tags: php, error-handling

How would I get:

```
print (!$getTemplate) ? "Cannot Find Template File!" : "Template OK!";
```

to be used as:

```
if (!$getTemplate)
{
    echo "Cannot Find Template File!";
}
else
{
    echo "Template OK!";
};
```

I have tried so many way of doing it but cant find it, im still quite new at PHP.

Comment: There is a semicolon `;` at the end of the `if` statement. I didn't remove it while editing assuming that you might have put it intentionally. It should be removed.

Comment: Just tested and even with the semicolon removed it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell where this going wrong from your question but I would suggest this.

You could try using `file_exists();`

For example:

**Edited later to include OP's edit:**

```
$getTemplate = '/path/to/file.html';

if ( ! file_exists($getTemplate))
{
    echo "Cannot Find Template File!";
}
else
{
    echo "Template OK!";
    // fopen, fwrite, fclose here
}
```

Comment: I have already created the file dynamically, this is just to check if it is in the folder and the writes the string to a file.

Comment: Yes this code will check if it is in a folder, you would then add your writing to a file code to the else portion of above code.

Comment: Thanks! My day must have been to long. This works fine! i just have to clean it up.

Comment: :-) glad to have helped, accepting my answer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like this:

```
 echo (!$getTemplate ? "Cannot Find Template File!" : "Template OK!");
```

Comment: Ye i saw that and fixed it, i used `print` originally.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass that first expression you listed to the `echo` construct:

```
echo ( $getTemplate ? "Template OK!" : "Cannot find template file!" );
```

(Note: I removed the `!` and reversed the order of the ternary arguments to make it easier to follow.)

Comment: I need to eventually write the text to a file and cant get `fwrite` to work in that string.